# The best way to implement horizontal picker view

Tags: ios, picker

I need to implement horizontal picker view.

[image]

I've tried to rotate UIPickerView, but the problem is: there is a big distance between elements and it is possible to change selected item when scroll stops, not when it is scrolling.

Is the right way to do it?

[image]

Comment: You probably want to create your own picker from scratch if you are trying to achieve something close to the example you showed.

Comment: You can use `UICollectionView` to create this kind of UI.

Comment: Here good example for `UICollectionView` and `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` which may be helpful to you achieve this kind of functionality. **Refer this**      https://github.com/ink-spot/UPCarouselFlowLayout